# Loopback Verify User with lb-mandrill-connector: Uncaught AssertionError: template name should be defined

Tags: email, templates, mandrill, loopbackjs

I'm trying to send an email with mandrill through loopback `user.verify` method but I'm stucked in this error:

```
Uncaught AssertionError: template name should be defined
```

Googleing around I found this PR on loopback: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/pull/1517/files

but it seems that has not been merged as it brake TravisCI tests...

From that PR, I tried this workaround in my code:

```
let options = {
    type: 'email',
    port: '80',
    to: ac.email,
    from: app.get('emailFrom'),
    subject: 'Thanks for registering.',
    verifyHref: verifyHref,
    template: null,
    user: ac
};

var template = loopback.template(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../server/views/verify.ejs'));
options.html = template(options);
```

But it seems that loopback set a default template if no specified, any suggestion?

I'm running on `loopback#2.18`

Answer (score 2):

The solution here is not to do the `user.verify` but generate the token and then call `user.save` and proceed with the call to mandrill.

```
context.req.app.models.User.generateVerificationToken(user, function (err,token) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }

    user.verificationToken = token;
    user.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
        }
        else {
            var url = 'http://' + config.host + ':' + config.port + '/api/users/confirm?uid=2&redirect=/&token=' + token;
            var mandrill_client = new mandrill.Mandrill('XXXX');
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

```
let options = {
    type: 'email',
    port: '80',
    to: ac.email,
    from: app.get('emailFrom'),
    subject: 'Thanks for registering.',
    verifyHref: verifyHref,
    template: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../server/views/verify.ejs'),
    user: ac
};

user.verify(options, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
        next(err);
        return;
    }

    console.log('> verification email sent:', response);

    // render the response template
    context.res.render('response', {
        title: 'Signed up successfully',
        content: 'Please check your email and click on the verification link before logging in.',
        redirectTo: '/',
        redirectToLinkText: 'Log in'
    });
});
```

The loopback method user.verify compiles and renders the ejs template (via loopback.template) and sends the email via the Email datasource. Unfortunately you can't supply a different template engine .. it's hardcoded to ejs. I wanted to use nunjucks so had to override loopback.template to return the render method of nunjucks so that when loopback.template is called from user.verify it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled accross the issue today. Mandrill provides built-in template functionality where you you provide dynamic templates within your mandrill account and specify variables to populate using the mandrill connector. When template is provided template.name must exist or an assert statement will fail.

This is taken straight from the code:

`/**
 * Send transactional email with options
 *
 * Basic options:
 *
 * {
 *   from: { name: "evenemento", email: "crew@evenemento.co" },
 *   to: "hello@evenemento.co",
 *   subject: "Ho ho",
 *   text: "Plain text message",
 *   html: "<b>Html messages</b> put here"
 * }
 *
 * Full list of options are available here:
 * https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.nodejs.html#method=send
 *
 * if option template is set than message will be send as template:
 *
 * {
 *   from: { name: "evenemento", email: "crew@evenemento.co" },
 *   to: "hello@evenemento.co",
 *   subject: "Ho ho",
 *   template: {
 *      name: "signup-confirm",
 *      content: {
 *        name: "NewUser Name",
 *        accountId: "123456"
 *      }
 *   }
 * }`